# Grub won't find ubuntu after SD card installation on a UEFI compute stick

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, sd-card

I  have an intel compute stick that I'd like to dual boot Windows 10 and Xubuntu 18.04LTS.

I installed Xubuntu onto an inserted SD card. It installed fine, but when trying to boot, i am met with:

error: no such device: SD CARD UUID

error: unknown filesystem.

Entering rescue mode...

grub rescue>

what do I need to do to get this to boot?

Comment: Many systems will not boot SD cards. Can you plug card into an adapter so it sees it as a USB drive? Did you partition in advance and include an ESP - efi system partition (FAT32)? UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace New installs now use swap file, so swap partition now not required.

Comment: would i put the efi partition on my main drive? ie the emmc? basically, what i did was do a standard install onto the SD, then put grub on the windows drive,  hoping grub would see the SD card and boot from there.

Comment: If you have UEFI install already on internal drive, the installer will automatically use it. If you used BIOS install then you can install grub to internal drive. But that may or may not work to boot a SD card.

Comment: SOLVED! I created a second efi partition and a /boot partition on the main windows drive. linux now boots off the SD card

Comment: You can only have one working ESP per device. You can have multiple FAT32 but boot/esp flags can only be on one of them at a time. Probably having separate /boot partition, so system really is booting from that drive is what worked.